# cloning only the os (windows7)?

Tags: windows-7, ssd

im thinking to buy a SSD disk that is 128gb and my current HDD is 1TB (almost full),
so i was wondering if is there any application that allows me only copy the OS (Windows 7) and the programs installed but no the others files (videos, music, games, etc)

Note: this is only single partition, all the data are together in the same partition

Comment: Is your OS on a separate partition which fits on the SSD (good) or do you have one big 1TB partition (not so good..)?

Comment: yeap, i have only 1 partition, the OS and personal data , are in the same partition, im looking something that safely copy Win7 and Program Files Folder,

Comment: One approach would be to backup your personal data to a different drive, then delete it from your HDD, shrink your OS partition to fit the size of your SSD, and then following my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that your OS is on a separate partition and its size does not exceed the size of your SSD.

Using the [parted magic live-cd](http://partedmagic.com/doku.php?id=downloads) you can do the following:

1. Boot the **parted magic live-cd**
2. Start **gparted**

   1. *If you have a separate Windows 7 boot partition (~100MiB) on your HDD:* Create a 100MiB-sized partition on your SSD (be sure that it is [aligned correctly](http://lifehacker.com/5837769/make-sure-your-partitions-are-correctly-aligned-for-optimal-solid-state-drive-performance)) with partition type `0x07` (HPFS/NTFS/exFAT).

      *Note that gparted should use correct alignment per default.*
   2. Create a (second) partition using all available free space left on your SSD to be used for your Windows 7 system (again, be sure to use correct alignment) with partition type `0x07` (HPFS/NTFS/exFAT).

      To check if the *n*th partition on your SSD is aligned properly, use this command (where `/dev/sda` is your SSD):

      ```
      parted /dev/sda align-check opt n
      ```
3. Use **clonezilla** to

   1. clone the 100MiB HDD boot partition to the corresponding partition on your SSD
   2. clone the HDD Windows 7 partition to the corresponding (large) partition on your SSD
4. Reboot

   *If your SSD doesn't boot your cloned Windows 7 installation:* Insert your **Windows 7 DVD**, boot into rescue mode, fix the boot sector (will be called for automatically).

Afterwards your Windows 7 should boot flawlessly from your SSD.

---

[This guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/97242/how-to-migrate-windows-7-to-a-solid-state-drive/) describes most of the above steps more precisely (including steps to decrease the size of your system partition if it is too big); [this guide](http://www.ssdfreaks.com/content/664/how-to-clone-hdd-to-ssd-with-windows-7s-own-software) describes similar steps with only using Windows 7 tools.

Comment: This only works if its data is on another partition then the rest of his system.  My guess he has a single 1TB partition.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, that's why I stated the same in the very first sentence.